# WP 8.1 - Debug Universal App in device not working with VS 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

im trying to ebug my universal app from VS 2013 update 2 in my WP8.1 device but i have this error:

> Failed to deploy. Make sure another deployment or debugging session is
>   not in progress for the same emulator or device from a different
>   instance of Visual Studio: Error writing file
>   '%FOLDERID_SharedData%\PhoneTools\11.0\Debugger\bin\RemoteDebugger\msvsmon.exe'. Error 0x80070005: Access Denied.

I tried run as administrator and got the same error. Im using VS 2013 Update 1+2, Windows Phone 8.1 on my device (unlocked with WP8.1 developer tool).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Same happens if it is "Phone" app as well (not just with "Universal" app)

Comment: My phone had pending Windows Phone upgrade from version `8.10.12382.878` to `8.10.12397.895` (the device offered to upgrade, but said 'later') helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Usually, this error means there's a pending Windows Phone OS update.  Can you see if you have pending updates on the phone and restart?

In the remote case that still doesn't work, you can try reset the phone in about page to get the phone to a clean state.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/reset-my-phone

Answer (score 0):

Probably you installed the app before and then changed some settings in you AppManifest like the project-ID. Uninstall the previously installed version from your device or change the ID-settings back to what you used for the previous installation.