# Deploy to device fails when app is installed from store

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

On my development phone, I have my own app installed in current release from the store. My phone is registered as developer phone.

Now I´m writing an update for that app. In Visual Studio 2013, I wrote some updates and wanted to test them on my device, but I get an error:

```
 Error writing file '%FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL%\AppID\Project.dll'. Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.
```

And it doesn´t matter if I try to deploy a "debug" or a "release" build.

The only solution by now is to deinstall my (store) app and deploy then. But so I lose all my Settings and history data withih my app.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you give search on the error? MSDN had some solutions..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132498/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I experienced this error when I went to do some further work on our app a few months after I added an In-App purchase.

It seems that in order to test the in-app purchases, I had to set the ProductID in the WMAppManifest.xml file to be the same as that of our live app.

This makes the in-app purchasing testing work, but then fails with the above error the next time you want to deploy it to your phone.

If you change the ProductID in the manifest to something new (or back to what you had it as before) then this fixes the issue.